# Get fragment object in activity while using viewPagerviewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

Recently, I was trying to know **How to swipe through fragments using a *ViewPager***. I have to set text on a `TextView` which is in `Fragement` from the activity. I found that one can get the `Fragment` object from `ViewPager` using :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":0");
```

When I tried to do this in `onCreate()` method of activity, it always returns `null`. I assume that is because `Fragment` is not started yet. Then in which method I should try to access the fragment object so that I can send arguments to the fragment methods?

Answer (score 2):

This **two** answer **SOLVE** my problem.

**ANSWER 1:**

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(position);
```

**OR ANSWER 2:**

```
Fragment fragment = (Fragment) viewPager.getAdapter().
          instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a ViewPager and you want to access to a fragment which is inside a ViewPager, you can use this code:

```
Fragment currentFragment = (Fragment) viewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem()); //gets current fragment
//now you have to cast it to your fragment, let's say it's name is SenapatiFragment

((SenapatiFragment)currentFragment).someMethod(...); // you have now access to public fields and methods that are inside your fragment
```

Comment: Thanks..:) now I am able to get the fragment in the onCreate() method of activity. But the problem is when I am calling the method in onCreate(), the textview.setText in the fragment's method, gives null pointer exception. Could you please tell me why is this happening and how to resolve this?

Comment: There is a lot of possibilities, i could tell you more if you paste some more code, especially your fragment code and your activity code also.